# Automatically update a <div> part of an HTML if a new database record is added

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a simple page which contains some products in the database. What I want is to create some sort of an updater, if the user add a product then that specific div in the page will display the latest product added automatically.

I tried to view this link but it doesnt help at all we have different problem.

Anyway heres the function i have in php.

```
function recentlyAddeditems() {
echo '<h3>Recently Added Products</h3> <hr/>';
echo '<div id="main_section_widget">';



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());

if ($sql) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $category = $row['category'];

        echo "<a href=\"product.php?pid=$id\">$name | $category<br/></a>
                <hr/>
                ";
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '
        <p><br/><a href="recentitems.php">More items...</a></p>

    ';
}
}
```

and the  in html page

```
<div id="main_section_widget_cover" class="dates">
            <?php recentlyAddedItems(); ?>
        </div>
```

Is there a simpler way how to do this? I tried to read about ajax in jquery but still having confused without a concrete example.

Please help wizards of stack!!!

Comment: Since browsers are still mostly "stateless", you have to think about the two methods available for getting data to a client and see what your browser/Javascript can accommodate. You can PULL, which means poll the server and "pull back" changes with the result or restart the poll every X interval. Or you can fake a PUSH, which is where the server "pushes" changes to the client. PUSH is hard in most current browser because you have to fake it. Long polling is one technique.

Comment: You can use ajax to accomplish this but I warrant against this. You might put a large load on your server depending on how many viewers are on your site. But I've done this in the past and worked great. It would work with what @Jared Farrish said. Poll the server for changes.

Comment: I wouldn't mind about the load since its a lan based application,

the problem is how to go about it? where should i implement the ajax

Comment: You have to separate your presentation from the logic; ie, don't embed `echo`'s in your function so you can call it pure and get a result that can be reused in multiple places. Try an MVC or REST approach. CodeIgniter is a decent framework to get started with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want an example of a ajax in jquery here is a really simple example

```
<div id="main_section_widget_cover" class="dates"><div>

<script>
    $('#main_section_widget_cover').load('recentitems.php');
</script>
```

in recentitems.php

```
<?php recentlyAddedItems(); ?>
```

Thats it, thats all you need to do to do a basic ajax call

Comment: That means that I have to check the recentitems.php for any updates, but I want to check directly to the database and update if a new record was inserted.

Is there any other way?